# Auto merge in GIT using python script

Tags: git, python-3.x, git-merge

I wrote a auto merge script in python for auto merging between different branches.

I plan to use "External hooks" (This script is configured to run on GIT Repository server and script will get fire on each check-in) and pass arguments to this script like branches name as source and target.

But as soon as check-in is done, Script gets fired through "External Hooks", but "Git status" command from script as is follows :

```
logging.debug("GIT STATUS COMMAND")
statuscode = call('/usr/local/bin/git status')
logging.debug('after call %s'%statuscode)
```

and it throws error:

```
10/07/2015 04:45:15 PM Exception at GIT STATUS
10/07/2015 04:45:15 PM <class 'FileNotFoundError'>
```

Till now, I am referring this http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/git-automatic-merges-with-server-side-hooks-for-the-win/

Whole script is simple, checkout source branch and merge the same into target.

Any ideas, why i am seeing this error ?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly nothing to do with git itself.

If `call` here is actually `subprocess.call` (you did `from subprocess import call` perhaps?), note that the various `subprocess` module operations require one of two things:

- shell=True, or
- pre-split arguments

That is:

```
statuscode = call('/usr/local/bin/git status')
```

should perhaps read:

```
statuscode = call('/usr/local/bin/git status'.split())
```

or:

```
statuscode = call(['/usr/local/bin/git', 'status'])
```

or:

```
statuscode = call('/usr/local/bin/git status', shell=True)
```

or similar.

Comment: Yes i imported subprocess.call in the code above.I tried "statuscode = call('/usr/local/bin/git status', shell=True)"..it didnt throw "FilenotFound" exception, but it logged anything and program is not moved forward. Looked like it got stuck and not executing.  And other options didnt work either. Surprisingly script works fine on local machine under "git bash window" (on windows box)

Comment: I also tried following :                                                                           statuslog = subprocess.Popen('/usr/local/bin/git status', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
 (statusoutput, err) = statuslog.communicate()
 logging.debug('git status output : %s '%statusoutput)
....It didnt work either....this script worked fine on local windows machine under gitbash..but same script working on git repo server on linux.

Comment: `git status` writes its output to its standard output (and stderr if needed).  Without additional stuff in your `subprocess.call`, those will pass through to Python's stdout (and stderr).  I see from scanning the blog pages that the hook examples on the page are stripped-down and incomplete; the real hooks are included in the product, apparently.  [Edit: your second comment, which crossed with mine, has the extra stuff to capture stdout and stderr.  I think what you're having issues with here is purely Python though.]

Comment: i also think its something related with python. But i can't say much, as i am not python expert...i just picked little bit to write this script. Script was all working on local machine, so i was all excited...but same script is not working o Linux...so i am struggling here to work same script there.